# Hard time to install nvidia-340 driver on Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia

I just upgraded to the new UBUNTU 20.04 but my nvidia-340 driver stop to work, i tried so much solutions over the net but nothing works for me...

tried to purge nvidia-* and to reinstall, sudo apt-get -f install and more of those solutions and nothing has worked for now..

here is some outpots of lshw and dmks status and more///

[image: GUI UBUNTU ADDITIONAL DRIVER INSTALLER]

[image: driver auto install]
[image: ubuntu-drivers autoinstall]

[image: DKMS OUTPOT]

[image: lshw -C display]

i am having hard time to install it and tried to `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-340_340.108-0ubuntu5.20.04.2_amd64.deb`

but nothing works and i am still can not install the driver.. i even tried to download the .deb and run it by myself with chmod but its still send me this error...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg-divert --list | grep libGL.so.1
```

This should display either `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib` or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1`. **According to the output it should be the first one.** Then, execute the following

```
sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove --divert "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib"
```

After which, you can try reinstalling your driver

Comment: dpkg-divert --list | grep libGL.so.1 aint give any output and 'sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove --divert "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib"
' raise a error;  'dpkg-divert: error: --remove needs a single argument' do you have any clue or even other idea?! thanks for the responding !